# How to get access to data only after they are loaded?

Tags: vue.js

I have got Vue.extend:

```
data: function ()  {
  return {
     questions: []
  }

  },
  ready() 
  { 
    this.getQuestionsContent(),
    this.foo()
  },
  methods: 
  {

     getQuestionsContent()
     {
        this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/questions.json').then(function(response)
        {
          this.questions = response.data;

        }); 

      },
      foo()
      {
        console.log(this.$get('questions'));
      }

  }
```

`getQuestionsContent` retrieve content. But when I try to print it with: `console.log(this.$get('questions'));` on Chrome Console I see only empty object. It's seems that it's not loaded at moment of printing it with `console.log`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback function is not running within the scope of your vue component.  You need to bind `this` to the function so that you can set `this.questions`:

```
this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/questions.json').then(function(response)
    {
      this.questions = response.data;

    }.bind(this));
```

You won't have access to the questions until the callback function of the asynchronous request.  So calling `this.foo()` immediately after sending the request won't ever show data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with asynchronous function. Maybe something like that :

```
this.getQuestionsContent(function(questions) {
    console.log(questions);
})
```

with

```
getQuestionsContent(callback) {
    this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/questions.json').then(function(response)
    {
        callback(response.data);
    }); 
}
```

The callback function is called only when you get the response from the server.

Comment: Can I do same with `activate Hook` ?